# GORM inhertiance and fetching the super class

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have the following grails domain objects

```
abstract class A {
    String name
}

class B extends A {
    String propertySpecificToB
}

class C extends A {
    String propertySpecificToC
}
```

and I can successfully save them to my database (which in this case is MongoDB). However, I would like to list all the names of the rows in my database, so I do something like:

```
A.list()
```

But, that throws an InstantiationException as it tries to create instances of the abstract class A. How can I list off all rows (regardless of which class it is). I could make A non-abstract, but it would never be valid to have a A. Also, I'd like to place some abstract methods in A.

I'd really just like it to return a list of A, with the list actually containing Bs and Cs.

I found a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720533/abstract-classes-in-gorm-relationships), but that didn't solve this problem.

Comment: Ok, I just tried my code with Hibernate instead of the mongo plugin, and it seems to be working how I wanted it to work. So perhaps this is a bug with the mongo plugin?

Comment: With the _mongo-db_ plugin this works if you don't make the base class `abstract`. I know that's not ideal but it might be a workaround.